# TextField in Table behavior

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to use the new SwiftUI `Table` with `TextField`s in each row.

However, the behavior of the text field's is weird, for 3 reasons:

1. Clicking on a text field takes about 1 second for the focus to occur
2. Anything that is **not** selected inside of a text field appears invisible until you change the text (only on dark mode?)
3. You can only click on the part of the text field with text, otherwise no focus occurs

### Reproduction:

1. Ensure that macOS Montery Beta 1/2 & Xcode 13 Beta 1/2 are installed
2. Create a new blank SwiftUI project, and set its deployment target to 12.0
3. Paste the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = [TestStruct(text: "Test"), TestStruct(text: "Bla"), TestStruct(text: "FooBar")]
    @State var selection = Set<TestStruct.ID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        Table($data, selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("Col") { $item in
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $item.text)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TestStruct: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
}
```

4. Test it out by clicking one of the text fields (only works if you click the part with visible text)

Is anybody able to reproduce the behavior listed above, and are there any possible solutions? Or is this a bug with SwiftUI?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I want to do something similar.

Comment: Me too, and how many rows do you need that it becomes slow? 100 or 500 or 1000?

Comment: This is old and no longer seems to be an issue. Copying the question's code into a SwiftUI project with Xcode 15.2 and running the app as a macOS app on macOS 14.3.1 results in none of the issues mentioned in the question.